# How to transform lattice in VESTA

Tags: crystallography, vesta

Can anyone please help me transform $\ce{LiCoO2}$ hexagonal cell ($a \times a \times c$) to orthorhombic cell ($a \times a \sqrt{3} \times 1$) and hexagonal cell ($a \sqrt{3} \times a \sqrt{3}\times 1$)?[image: Image of cell transformations from a hexagonal a x a x c cell]

Comment: Have you tried `Edit -> Edit Data -> Unit cell` option? From there you can change the unit cell as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you. I found transform function. But when I entered the transform matrix, it show something strange. I would appreciate if you can show me how to determine transformation matrix.

Comment: I'm sorry but I personally am not experienced in this regard. That is why I posted what I know as a comment instead of as an answer. If you send me the coordinates file, I'll try to do this and see if that works for me.

Comment: Please find the structure in this website: https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-24850/

Comment: Is this the required orthorhombic [result](https://dms.uom.lk/s/X8R7Z6oKW3zJkKn)?

Comment: I can do using two ways 1. In OVITO replicate in different direction and cut the periodic unit in orthogonal box. Method two simple using software called atomsk, just type this command "atomsk POSCAR1 -orthogonal-cell vasp"

Comment: @PBH no, it is not. it is orthorhombic, not cubic.

Comment: @pranavkumar thank you, it sound great. I need 3√×3√×1 cell as well.

Comment: Replicate in Ovito and affine-transform only simulation box as required ,keep atoms inside new cell and delete rest, make sure not to include periodic atoms. You can talk this conversation in vasp chat group, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109983/vasp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**structure 1**
[image]
**Method affine transformation of simulation box after replicating in X and Y in ovito**
[image]

*OUTPUT: POSCAR*

```
POSCAR file written by OVITO
1.0
        2.8428978920         0.0000000000         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000         4.9240398407         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000         0.0000000000        14.1456146240
   Li   Co    O
    6    6   12
Direct
     0.000000000         0.000000000         0.000000000
     0.500000461         0.166666663         0.333332985
     0.000000000         0.333333809         0.666666981
    -0.000000000         0.666667086         0.333332985
     0.499999958         0.500000436         0.000000000
     0.499999455         0.833334173         0.666666981
     0.000000000         0.333333809         0.166666998
    -0.000000000        -0.000000000         0.500000000
     0.500000461         0.166666663         0.833333019
     0.000000000         0.666667086         0.833333019
     0.499999455         0.833334173         0.166666998
     0.499999958         0.500000436         0.500000000
    -0.000000000        -0.000000000         0.239586996
     0.500000461         0.166666663         0.093745997
     0.500000461         0.166666663         0.572920049
    -0.000000000         0.333333809         0.427080019
    -0.000000000         0.333333809         0.906254011
    -0.000000000        -0.000000000         0.760412970
     0.000000000         0.666667086         0.093745997
    -0.000000000         0.666667086         0.572920049
     0.499999958         0.500000436         0.239586996
     0.499999455         0.833334173         0.427080019
     0.499999455         0.833334173         0.906254011
     0.499999958         0.500000436         0.760412970
```

**structure2**
[image]
**Method affine transformation of simulation box after replicating in X and Y in ovito**
[image]

*OUTPUT: POSCAR*

```
POSCAR file written by OVITO
1.0
        4.9240450859         0.0000000000         0.0000000000
        2.4620173651         4.2643450666         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000         0.0000000000        14.1456146240
   Li   Co    O
    9    9   18
Direct
     0.000000000         0.000000000         0.000000000
     0.333333430        -0.000000000         0.333332985
    -0.000000007         0.333333975         0.666666981
    -0.000000018         0.666666944         0.333332985
     0.666665892        -0.000000000         0.666666981
     0.333333114         0.333333891         0.000000000
     0.666666524         0.333333835         0.333332985
     0.333332722         0.666667838         0.666666981
     0.666666229         0.666667782         0.000000000
    -0.000000007         0.333333975         0.166666998
    -0.000000000        -0.000000000         0.500000000
     0.333333430        -0.000000000         0.833333019
    -0.000000018         0.666666944         0.833333019
     0.666665892        -0.000000000         0.166666998
     0.333332722         0.666667838         0.166666998
     0.333333114         0.333333891         0.500000000
     0.666666524         0.333333835         0.833333019
     0.666666229         0.666667782         0.500000000
     0.000000000        -0.000000000         0.239586996
     0.333333430        -0.000000000         0.093745997
     0.333333430        -0.000000000         0.572920049
    -0.000000007         0.333333975         0.427080019
    -0.000000007         0.333333975         0.906254011
    -0.000000000         0.000000000         0.760412970
    -0.000000018         0.666666944         0.093745997
    -0.000000018         0.666666944         0.572920049
     0.666665892        -0.000000000         0.427080019
     0.666665892        -0.000000000         0.906254011
     0.333333114         0.333333891         0.239586996
     0.666666524         0.333333835         0.093745997
     0.666666524         0.333333835         0.572920049
     0.333332722         0.666667838         0.427080019
     0.333332722         0.666667838         0.906254011
     0.333333114         0.333333891         0.760412970
     0.666666229         0.666667782         0.239586996
     0.666666229         0.666667782         0.760412970
```

**Load POSCAR > show periodic image > affine transformation > manual selection > delete selected atoms >export as POSCAR**

**NOTE: During delete of extra atom outside simulation box don't include periodically equivalent atoms in boundaries**

Comment: Is it Ovito pro version?

Comment: I am using old linux version 2.9 .

Comment: I just downloaded version 3.6 on my macbook and I could not find periodic image and manual selection

Comment: check option replicate

Answer (score 1):

When you change the lattice, you actually change the crystal structure (don't confuse the lattice, a geometrical object, with the crystal structure, a real object).

First of all you have to consider the space group types of your starting and final structures and verify that a group-subgroup relationship holds between them. If yes, you can transform the structure.

Than you can use the tools avaliable at the Bilbao Crystallographic Server for transforming your structure. It is imperatuve that you use a correct transfomation matrix. At this point the Server will give you the atomic positions in the Wyckoff sites for the new space group. You can save this structure as a CIF file and import it in Vesta.